# How to efficiently package large number of drawable images for different resolutions in Android?

Tags: android

I have an image application like a SlideShow on Android and want to support multiple screen resolutions viz. ldpi,mdpi,hdpi etc. I have a large number of images and having a copy of every image for each screen resolution will make my application size big. How to package them in an efficient manner so that the application size remains small ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to support multiple screen densities, you don't really have to provide all of the images per density (in case they look about the same, only resized).

You could simply put the highest quality images on drawable-xhdpi or drawable-xxhdpi, and downscale&view the images at runtime for other screens (Android does it automatically, but in some cases you might want to do further downscaling, depending on the images).

The downside is it requires more work on lower density screens, and images might look different than what you want them to be.

It's a common thing to put icons in different densities folders so that the resizing won't damage the quality in any way (including the blurry effect).

Comment: Yes, please try to support the best quality images, since if you do the opposite, images will be scaled up and become blurry.